# Why Custom preference does not show?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement this custom preference https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/515681
**but the preference does not show :-(((**

### [image]

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**

**It turns out it works on Gingerbread but not on KitKat :-((((**

PLEASE THE OTHER; NOT CUSTOM PREFERENCE, ARE SHOWING NORMALLY WITHOUT PROBLEMS...

---

This is **MyPreferencesActivity**:

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("prefs");
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

// add a validator to the "numberofCircles" preference so that it only
// accepts numbers
Preference circlePreference = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("numberOfCircles");

// add the validator
circlePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(numberCheckListener);
}
}
```

This is my **prefs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/frankandrobot.glwallpapervideodemo.com" >

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="touch"
    android:title="Enable Touch" >
</CheckBoxPreference>

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="numberOfCircles"
    android:title="Number of Circles" >
</EditTextPreference>

<frankandrobot.glwallpapervideodemo.com.IconCheckBoxPreference
        android:key="help"
        android:title="Ciao"
        app:icon="@drawable/icon" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is the **Custom preference**:

```
package frankandrobot.glwallpapervideodemo.com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class IconCheckBoxPreference extends CheckBoxPreference {
private Drawable mIcon;

public IconCheckBoxPreference(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    this.setLayoutResource(R.layout.icon_checkbox_preference);

    this.mIcon = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IconPreference, defStyle, 0).getDrawable(R.styleable.IconPreference_icon);
}

public IconCheckBoxPreference(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(final View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    if ((imageView != null) && (this.mIcon != null)) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(this.mIcon);
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the icon for this Preference with a Drawable.
 *
 * @param icon The icon for this Preference
 */
public void setIcon(final Drawable icon) {
    if (((icon == null) && (this.mIcon != null)) || ((icon != null) && (!icon.equals(this.mIcon)))) {
        this.mIcon = icon;
        this.notifyChanged();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the icon of this Preference.
 *
 * @return The icon.
 * @see #setIcon(Drawable)
 */
public Drawable getIcon() {
    return this.mIcon;
}
}
```

This is my **attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="IconPreference">
    <attr name="icon" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: You're using deprecated APIs. Read about PreferenceFragment.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Thanks Fouad, yes, but it MUST work even if I do not use the fragment

Comment: check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html and try this example it will works on kitkat   http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/example-of-using-preferencefragment.html

Comment: @rajahsekar thank you rajahsekar, but that is not the point, it MUST work without fragment!

Comment: TO work this you have to use isvalidfragment it is add in kitkat please check following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973034/isvalidfragment-android-api-19   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868643/why-does-kit-kat-require-the-use-of-the-isvalidfragment

Comment: @rajahsekar but I do not get any exception, if I do not use fragments then I do to have to use isvalidfragment. Additionally, other custom preferences work perfectly, therefore the problem must lie somewhere else

Comment: What does "does not show" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks CommonsWare, please see the picture added. Thanks!

Comment: Have you inspected the activity using Hierarchy View? Are the widgets there (but are transparent, or black-on-black, or `View.INVISIBLE`)? Or are there no widgets at all?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have, there is no widget: there are the widgets for the first two Preferences but the third is simply non existent, there is not widget at all for the third Preference

Comment: Hmmm... OK, let me see if I can reproduce the problem. I'll chime back in here once I have, with more comments or an answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you very much CommonsWare !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is: `CheckBoxPreference`, at least for Android 4.1+, supports `android:icon`, and so you do not need your own custom preference class.

The only reason for my hedging on 4.1 is that I just haven't tried it on anything older.

Comment: thank you, I will try and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: thanks that was the issue! But the problem remains that `android:icon`is not supported on Gingerbread.

Comment: @LisaAnne: Then use two versions of your preference XML. In `res/xml-v11/`, put a file that uses `android:icon`. In `res/xml/`, put a file that uses `IconCheckBoxPreference`.